# Poor man's reverse proxy: caching using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, cache

## Poor man's reverse proxy: caching using mod_rewrite

I am pretty sure somebody already solved this problem somehow. Long story short I want to cache `GET` requests to my PHP script. The script saves the content into the file at `/cache/{uri}/index.{type}/index.{type}`. Headers are set by an .htaccess file in the same directory, e.g. `RequestHeader set Content-type "application/json;charset=utf-8"`.

Here what it looks like:

```
{webroot}/
    .htaccess
    cache/
        caching/
            test/
                index.json/
                    .htaccess
                    index.json
    index.php
```

Contents of `{webroot}/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Append ".html", if there is no extension...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /$1.html [L]

# ...and redirect to cache directory ("/cache")
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(\w+)$ /cache/$1/index.$2/index.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Contents of `{webroot}/cache/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# If no file found, redirect back to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Contents of `{webroot}/cache/caching/test/index.json/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Cache till 5th May, 2012
RewriteCond %{TIME} >20120518194510
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?/$1 [L]

RequestHeader set Content-type "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
</IfModule>
```

Now for `http://localhost/caching/test.json` the cached version is served. However, the problem is that the file is accessible directly via `http://localhost/cache/caching/test/index.json/index.json` and I cannot figure out how to prevent access to it by either throwing an error page or redirecting to index.php or any other way.

Sage advice is very welcome, because I barely know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squash any requests to the cache directory that don't have an environment variable stating that they were properly redirected by the root.

Change your rule in the root `.htaccess`, to tag all redirecting requests with an environment variable saying that they're allowed internal redirects, instead of direct access:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(\w+)$ /cache/$1/index.$2/index.$2 [L,ENV=FROM_ROOT:1]
```

The tricky part is that the environment variables get renamed for an internal redirect.  So, add something like this to the `index.json/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FROM_ROOT} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?/$1 [L]
```